# Решение задачи Python. IndexError: string Index ot of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Кодирование осуществляется следующим образом:
`s = 'aaaabbсaa'` преобразуется в `'a4b2с1a2'`, то есть группы одинаковых символов исходной строки заменяются на этот символ и количество его повторений в этой позиции строки.

```py
vvod = input()
c = 1
povt = 1
for i in range((len(vvod))):
    while vvod[(c-1)] == vvod[c]:
        povt += 1
        c += 1
    print(vvod[c-1] + str(povt), end='')
    povt = 1
    c += 1
```

все выводится правильно, только когда призодит время вывода последних букв, он пишет, что `IndexError: string Index ot of range`

---

Я уже решил сам эту задачу, но способ, которым я исправил ошибку... Я ору...

```py
vvod = input()
idea = vvod + '.'
c = 1
povt = 1
for i in range((len(vvod))):
    if c > len(vvod):
        break
    while idea[(c-1)] == idea[c]:
        povt += 1
        c += 1
    print(idea[c-1] + str(povt), end='')
    povt = 1
    c += 1
```

Comment: ну возьми отладчик или функцию print и посмотри к каким элементам идет обращение и сколько этих элементов всего.

Comment: И прекращайте писать на Python как на Pascal. У этого языка совсем другие идиомы.

Comment: Я сам люблю notepad++ и sublime, но при таких ошибкаих иду в более хороший Visual Studio Code. Достаточно поставить точку остановки и на последней итерации посмотреть значение переменных для отладки. Быстро поймешь в чем дело.

Comment: @ShamusRezol для этого не нужен VS Code, хватит и pdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если убрать из вашего кода лишнее, то останется:

```
vvod = 'aaaabbсaa'
povt = 1
for i in range(1, len(vvod) + 1):
    if i == len(vvod) or vvod[i-1] != vvod[i]:
        print(vvod[i-1] + str(povt), end='')
        povt = 1
    else:
        povt += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

На ~последней итерации цикла `for` переменная `c` становится равной `len(vvod)`. То есть равной максимальному индексу + 1 (так как индексы начинаются с нуля). Из этого вылезает ошибка на следующем входе (+-. Вашу реализацию сложно понять. Поработайте над кодом..) в цикл.

Можно сказать, что когда переменная `c` после последней строчке цикла равна `len(vvod)`, то цикл `for` прошел все символы, а значит следующий вход в цикл несколько некоректен. Можно это исправить добавив условие проверки перед телом цикла вроде `if c == len(vvod): break`, но лучше написать правильней все с нуля...

---

```
string  =input()
result  =str()
repeats =int()

for index, char in enumerate(string):

  if index != 0 and char == string[index - 1]:

    """ Текущий символ такой же, что и предыдущий.
        Увеличиваем счетчик:
    """
    repeats=repeats + 1

    """ Блокируем добавление повторяющегося символа:
    """
    continue

  else:

    if repeats:

      """ Учет повтора закончен.
      """
      result=result + str(repeats + 1)

    """ Сбросим счетчик:
    """
    repeats=int()

  """ Добавляем уникальный символ:
  """
  result=result + char

print(result)
```

Можно навернуть все куда компактней, но в качестве демонстрации это будет лучше.

Comment: Используйте для комментария `#` вместо `"""`. И забудьте про выравнивание по знаку равно в начале вашего кода.

Comment: почемубы не уровнять ? по пеп чительность важна. или нет?

Comment: Без проблем вы можете использовать это в вашем коде, но у меня свой стиль. Идти против начертаной схемы работы мне неприятно. Если я серьезно работаю над программой, то комментарии удаются шедеврально огромными. Это оформило мой стиль. То есть мне неудобно использовать однострочные # из за их вида. А выравниванием мне удобней читать свой же код. Я придерживаюсь баланса хорошо выглядит / понятен.

Answer (score 0):

Поделюсь своим вариантом без использования индексации:

```py
inp = input('Введите произвольную строку:')
prev = '' # предыдущий символ
repeat = 1 # счетчик повторов
result = [] # буфер результатов

# проход по символам полученной строки
for cur in inp:
    # если предыдущий и текущий символы равны, то наращиваем счетчик
    if prev == cur: 
        repeat += 1
    # если предыдущий и текущий символы неравны и предыдущий не пустой,
    # то сбрасываем результат в буфер и обнуляем счетчик
    elif (prev != cur) and (prev != ''):
        result.append(f'{prev}{repeat}')
        repeat = 1
    # передача текущего символа в предыдущий
    prev = cur

# сброс последнего результата в буфер
result.append(f'{prev}{repeat}')

# генерация строки результата
print(''.join(result))
```

Результат выполнения:

```
> Введите произвольную строку:aaadddddffcsserrrrrrraassss
a3d5f2c1s2e1r7a2s4
```